Applying for B1B2 US visa while I’m in Canada
I am holder of Philippine passport. Right now I’m in Canada, holding a tourist visa status. Can I apply for B1B2 visa at the US border to enter US?

You cannot apply for a US visa at the border, it must be done at a consulate ahead of time. You can technically apply for a US visa in Canada, but it is usually done for employment visas, they might not want to consider a tourist application out of country of residency.

note that even when allowed, appointment wait times for US visas at Canadian consulates are generally quite long, too long in most cases to wait while visiting Canada as a tourist

Just to emphasize @mlc’s comment: we’re talking about nearly 2 years wait time at any of the consulates in Canada… while in Manila it’s only a month at this time.

Contrary to many other countries, the US allows applications anywhere, not just in your country of residence, but it may not make much sense (especially with the very long wait times in some places like Canada), it may be more difficult to get all the relevant paperwork while away from home, it may take longer to process the application as they may want to check things with the consulate in your home country, and it may raise questions.

@jcaron I'm not sure that's true. Canada and Mexico (and adjacent islands) are special cases and allow non residents to come for stamping from within the US
